docker socket used to connect to docker daemon
I have a docker and docker desktop installed on the fresh Ubuntu 24.04.
After restart the system I have docker daemon running
$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-11-11 11:29:55 CET; 26min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 2450 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 13
     Memory: 99.8M (peak: 101.3M)
        CPU: 509ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─2450 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
...
Nov 11 11:29:55 ot systemd[1]: Started docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 11 11:29:55 ot dockerd[2450]: time="2024-11-11T11:29:55.895923442+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"


So, docker looks ok and is listening on the /run/docker.sock.
But when I try to start any app with docker or just execute docker command I got the following error:
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/ot/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

so, command try to connect to the socket in my home dir.
Problem is solved when I run Docker Desktop application. But 2 questions still present for me:
1 - I don't understand why console command try to connect to the local socket file instead of system one and why it fixed when Docker Desktop is running?
2 - how to fix this issue to be able to start docker without Docker Desktop app is running?
probably first question is more important for me...
thanks for your help!
start docker desktop app fixes the problem, but I dont understand why and how to make docker command workable without starting docker desktop app.

It looks like your CLI is configured to talk to Docker in rootless mode. Have you had that installed? To fix it, you can try setting the DOCKER_HOST environment variable using export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock. On a clean install that's not needed though, so there might be a config file in your ~/.docker directory that sets the wrong endpoint.

You don't need Docker Desktop on a native-Linux system.  One of the things it does is to change the default Docker socket location for CLI commands; docker context use default will switch it back.
